# How to get hidden associative array field values inside jQuery post using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to get the value of associative hidden fields array in PHP by posting it through jquery ajax, currently I am trying in this way

Here, **HTML Code is:**

```
<input type="hidden" class="override_arr" name="override_arr[][id]" value="1">';
<input type="hidden" class="override_arr" name="override_arr[][override_price_second]" value="5">';
<input type="hidden" class="override_arr" name="override_arr[][override_price_third]" value="10">
```

**Jquery Code**

```
var new_override_arr = [];
 $('input.override_arr').each(function(i, elem) {
       new_override_arr.push({
       'id': $(elem).attr('id'),
       'override_price_second': $(elem).val(),
        'override_price_third': $(elem).val(),
         });
   });
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('new_override_arr', new_override_arr);

**Call Ajax**
$.ajax({
   url:'sa-store-view.php',
   type:'POST',
   data:formData,
   success:function(result){
   }
});
```

**Try to get value in php file(sa-store-view.php)**

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST['new_override_arr']);
?>
```

**but displaying like this**

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`.serialize()` should work

```
$.ajax({
   url:'sa-store-view.php',
   type:'POST',
   data: $('input.override_arr').serialize(),
   success:function(result){
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let PHP know that FormData element is an array

```
formData.append('new_override_arr[]', new_override_arr);
```